# Why do I get GPG error when running apt-update for lenny-backports?

Tags: debian, apt, debian-lenny

Alright, so I'm trying to upgrade  (if you could call it so) to lenny-backports as seen [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/287118/is-debian-lenny-backports-safe-to-use-on-lenny), but I ran into this error when running `apt-get update`:

```
W: GPG error: http://backports.debian.org lenny-backports Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A*numbers and letters*A
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

The line I added to sources.list is as follows:

```
deb      http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports lenny-backports main
```

And as Womble asked in previous question here is the version of debian-archive-keyring no matter what is that..

```
dpkg -l debian-archive-keyring
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Cfg-files/Unpacked/Failed-cfg/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Hold/Reinst-required/X=both-problems (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                       Version                    Description
+++-==========================-==========================-====================================================================
ii  debian-archive-keyring     2009.01.31                 GnuPG archive keys of the Debian archive
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version of the debian-archive-keyring package is out of date.  You need to upgrade it to the latest version available in lenny -- an `apt-get install debian-archive-keyring` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://subkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys 16BA136C
gpg --export 16BA136C | apt-key add -
```

Comment: Should I use my key instead of `16BA136C` ?

Comment: no use that key

Comment: Eeeew... manual key import ftl.

Comment: you really should use the packages, not manual key import. go with @womble's answer